# Python Sorting in a List of Dictionaries by Numbers

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries that I'm trying to sort. This is what I have so far:

```py
output_list = [{'interface': '0/20', 'mac': '01:23:45:67:89:AB'},
               {'interface': '0/16', 'mac': '12:34:56:78:9A:BC'},
               {'interface': '0/31', 'mac': '23:45:67:89:AB:CD'},
               {'interface': '0/5', 'mac': '34:56:78:9A:BC:DE'},
               {'interface': '0/3', 'mac': '45:67:89:AB:CD:EF'}]

mac_list = sorted(output_list, key=lambda d: d['interface'])

pprint(mac_list)
```

However, it's not sorting the dictionaries the way I want.

```py
"C:\Program Files\Python310\python.exe" "C:/Scripts/Python/test1.py"
[{'interface': '0/16', 'mac': '12:34:56:78:9A:BC'},
 {'interface': '0/20', 'mac': '01:23:45:67:89:AB'},
 {'interface': '0/3', 'mac': '45:67:89:AB:CD:EF'},
 {'interface': '0/31', 'mac': '23:45:67:89:AB:CD'},
 {'interface': '0/5', 'mac': '34:56:78:9A:BC:DE'}]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

How can I get it to sort it so it looks like this:

```py
[{'interface': '0/3', 'mac': '45:67:89:AB:CD:EF'},
 {'interface': '0/5', 'mac': '34:56:78:9A:BC:DE'},
 {'interface': '0/16', 'mac': '12:34:56:78:9A:BC'},
 {'interface': '0/20', 'mac': '01:23:45:67:89:AB'},
 {'interface': '0/31', 'mac': '23:45:67:89:AB:CD'}]
```

Comment: what if you had a `3/7` interface value?

Comment: is it possible for an `interface` to be any other format? `None`, empty string, etc?

Comment: It is, but previous code above that's not shown will only return interfaces starting with `0/XX` in the `output_list`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the number out of the string:

```
sorted(output_list, key=lambda d: int(d['interface'].split("/")[1]))
```

This assumes that the first part of the interface won't change.

If it changes, you need to reformat both parts with the leading zero:

```
sorted(output_list, key=lambda d: "/".join([f"{int(x):02d}" for x in d['interface'].split("/")]))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
mac_list = sorted(output_list, key=lambda d: int(d['interface'].split("/")[1]))
```

If `interface` values could start with something other than `0`, and you want it to be part of the sorted value, then you could use something like:

```
mac_list = sorted(output_list, key=lambda d: int(d['interface'].split("/")[0]) * 10000 + int(d['interface'].split("/")[1]))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you always have `0/???`. Try this:

```
mac_list  = sorted(output_list, key= lambda x: int(x['interface'][2:]))
```

Output:

```
[{'interface': '0/3', 'mac': '45:67:89:AB:CD:EF'},
 {'interface': '0/5', 'mac': '34:56:78:9A:BC:DE'},
 {'interface': '0/16', 'mac': '12:34:56:78:9A:BC'},
 {'interface': '0/20', 'mac': '01:23:45:67:89:AB'},
 {'interface': '0/31', 'mac': '23:45:67:89:AB:CD'}]
```

If maybe have ???/???. try this: (*How about convert `1/3 to 1.3`?*)

```
# 1/3 -> 1.3 then get as float and sort
sorted(output_list, key= lambda x: float(x['interface'].replace('/', '.')))

# or as string
sorted(output_list, key= lambda x: (int(x['interface'][:1]),int(x['interface'][2:])))
```

Output:

```
[{'interface': '0/5', 'mac': '34:56:78:9A:BC:DE'},
 {'interface': '0/16', 'mac': '12:34:56:78:9A:BC'},
 {'interface': '0/20', 'mac': '01:23:45:67:89:AB'},
 {'interface': '0/31', 'mac': '23:45:67:89:AB:CD'},
 {'interface': '1/3', 'mac': '45:67:89:AB:CD:EF'}]
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if the first number of interface can be more than zero but if not this change helps. You want to only check the number after /:

```
mac_list = sorted(output_list, key=lambda d: int(d["interface"][2:]))
```

output is:

```
[{'interface': '0/3', 'mac': '45:67:89:AB:CD:EF'}, {'interface': '0/5', 'mac': '34:56:78:9A:BC:DE'}, {'interface': '0/16', 'mac': '12:34:56:78:9A:BC'}, {'interface': '0/20', 'mac': '01:23:45:67:89:AB'}, {'interface': '0/31', 'mac': '23:45:67:89:AB:CD'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`natsort`](https://pypi.org/project/natsort/) for natural sorting:

```
from natsort import natsorted

mac_list = natsorted(output_list, key=lambda d: d['interface'])
```

Or split and convert to integers:

```
mac_list = sorted(output_list,
                  key=lambda d: tuple(map(int, d['interface'].split('/'))))
```

output:

```
[{'interface': '0/3', 'mac': '45:67:89:AB:CD:EF'},
 {'interface': '0/5', 'mac': '34:56:78:9A:BC:DE'},
 {'interface': '0/16', 'mac': '12:34:56:78:9A:BC'},
 {'interface': '0/20', 'mac': '01:23:45:67:89:AB'},
 {'interface': '0/31', 'mac': '23:45:67:89:AB:CD'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than having a cumbersome looking lambda expression as the *key* argument, it might be clearer to have a separate function to handle to tuple construction:-

```
output_list = [{'interface': '0/20', 'mac': '01:23:45:67:89:AB'},
               {'interface': '0/16', 'mac': '12:34:56:78:9A:BC'},
               {'interface': '0/31', 'mac': '23:45:67:89:AB:CD'},
               {'interface': '0/5', 'mac': '34:56:78:9A:BC:DE'},
               {'interface': '0/3', 'mac': '45:67:89:AB:CD:EF'}]

def mt(s):
    return tuple(map(int, s['interface'].split('/')))

mac_list = sorted(output_list, key=mt)

print(mac_list)
```